# What US taxes are due for US stock bought via ESPP when I was in USA and sold after I returned to India?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, capital-gains-tax, dtaa

I was in USA and purchased few US stocks in 2007 through US broker and ESPP stocks through my employer. I moved back to India in 2012. I sold those US stocks in 2014. I have submitted W8-BEN forms to US broker and statements show my Indian address. Do I need to pay federal taxes in USA or do I need to pay the report and pay taxes in India?

Answer (score 1):

From an Indian Tax point of view, you can bring back all the assets acquired during the period you were NRI back to India tax free. Subject to a 7 years period. i.e. all the assets / funds / etc should be brought back to India within 7 years. It would still be treated as There are certain conditions / paperwork. Please consult a CA.

Comment: Do I need to pay US taxes for those stocks? I am interacting with CPA in USA but it is still unclear if I need to pay US taxes.